# add latex to rmarkdown to wrap long lines using listings package

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Long urls do not break when knitting to PDF in RStudio. This [can be solved](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/066-listings-breaklines.Rnw) with the `listings` package if using `.Rnw`, but I'm not sure what can be done if using RMarkdown.

It seems like it's [possible to include some LaTeX commands](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html), but I have not figured out a way to implement the `listings` solution in `.Rmd`.

I tried:

````
---
title: "my title"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{listings}
output: 
  pdf_document
---

render_listings()

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  library(knitr)
  render_listings()
```

```{r url, include=TRUE}
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/knitr-examples/master/066-listings-breaklines.Rnw"
```
````

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194569/8294

Comment: thanks, @TylerRinker. i'll need to read up on this a bit more. i tried adding `includes: in_header: listings.sty` in my `.rmd` and then created an empty `listings.sty` file in the same directory as my `.rmd`. i pasted `\usepackage{listings}` and `\lstset{breaklines=true}` into this `.sty` file. this led to a LaTeX error when i tried to knit the pdf. will look more into this.